# `find` claims it deleted the files, `ls` claims it didn't

Tags: linux, shell, rm

I tried to delete some images by matching them to a regular expression and I did this in two similar ways by now, both including piping the results of `find` to `rm`. First I found all the images that I wish to be deleted with this:

```
find . -type f -regex ".+-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg"
```

Which found a lot of results.

So I tried to delete them like this:

```
find . -type f -regex ".+-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

And then like this:

```
find . -type f -regex ".+-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg" | xargs rm
```

After both attempts, the `find` command no longer sees the images that I wanted to delete (when I run the first command again), but `ls` sees them, and so does Nautilus. Is there some kind of commit I should run in order to actually delete them from the hard disk?

I tried searching the `rm` man page for "commit" and the `find` man page for "remove", but haven't found anything significant.

Comment: Can you show out of `ls` for these images?

Comment: Well there's a lot, here's the last couple rows:

`yellow-zone-etna-36x36.png
yellow-zone-etna-615x250.png
yellow-zone-etna.png
Yuri-Beletsky-comets_labels_1362113263.jpg
ZANE-115x115.png
ZANE-150x150.png
ZANE-195x110.png
ZANE-300x195.png
ZANE-36x36.png
ZANE-610x250.png
Zane-AIRS1-.jpg
ZANE-cimss.jpg
ZANE-JTWC-forecast-track-115x115.png
ZANE-JTWC-forecast-track-150x150.png
ZANE-JTWC-forecast-track-195x110.png
ZANE-JTWC-forecast-track-300x170.png
ZANE-JTWC-forecast-track-36x36.png
ZANE-JTWC-forecast-track-610x250.png
ZANE-JTWC-forecast-track.png
ZANE-MTSAT-vis0.jpg
ZANE.png`

Comment: I don't think so, when I run the original `find . -type f -regex ".+-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg"` in the backup folder, it finds the images with multiple digits (the plus sign is there for that, and it seems to work)

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this question -- its answer is unlikely to be helpful for anyone else searching for information about using `find` for deletions. (Also, both question and accepted answer showcase bad practices; `find | xargs rm` is bad practice as compared to `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -- rm -rf --` or `find ... -exec rm -rf -- {} +`; the existing approaches given will have bugs when encountering unusual filenames).

Comment: Sure. I can't delete it, but i flagged it for moderation as suggested by the popup.

Comment: ... `-exec rm -rf` -- You probably don't want the `-r` option. You're deleting single `.jpg` files; the `-r` makes a difference only if you happen to have a directory whose name ends in `.jpg` (in which case you'll delete the directory and everything under it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match these filenames...

```
$ touch yellow-zone-etna-36x36.png yellow-zone-etna-615x250.png
$ find . -type f -regex ".+-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg"
$ # no output
```

because you have PNGs, you're looking for JPEGs, and you additionally have JPEGs that don't match the regex either.

Comment: Oh yeah... Crap, this is by far my worst stackoverflow question... Thanks man.